# XSSF Drop Down List Not Supporting MSExcell and Kingsoft Spreadsheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf, poi-hssf

```
XSSFDataValidationHelper validationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(firstSheet);
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 1, 4, 4);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(getAllNames()); 
DataValidation dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
```

Above code for drop down list working only in Libre Office Spread Sheet. Its not working in MS Ex-cell and King soft Spread Sheet. I researched in lots of blogs and Apache POI I didn't find any solution for that. If you guys solved this issue before please help me

Comment: Have you looked at https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#xssf.usermodel+%28.xlsx+format%29 Did you remember to add the data validation to the sheet?

Comment: yes i did but its not working

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found any solution for the same?

Comment: i already done this solution long ill post it